# Error handling in Meteor.js with SimpleSchema

Tags: meteor, collections, simple-schema

I'm working a project developing by Meteor.js & now I'm working for a validation something like that

```
import SimpleSchema from 'simpl-schema';

const CompanySchema = new SimpleSchema({
    company_name: {
        type: String,
        min: 5,
        max: 50,
        label: "Company Name"
    }
});

Company.attachSchema(CompanySchema);
```

but in the console showing like below image

[image]

but when trying to keep the "Error" like this way

```
console.log(err.Error);
```

it's showing

```
undefined
```

here is insert functionalities

```
Company.insert(
    {
        company_name: inputs.companyName.value,
    },
    function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log('Inserted successfully');
        }
    }
);
```

what's the issue actually.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please add the code of the method where the document gets inserted to the collection?

Comment: @Jankapunkt updated the question & add the functionalities below of my question

Comment: I think it should be `err.message`. Also, you can validate an object before using it in the insert as shown [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simpl-schema#validating-an-object).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your client-side Mongo insert fails it produces a [native `Error`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error). If you log it's `name`, `message` and `stack` it shows the expected properties of an `Error`:

```
Company.insert(
    {
        company_name: inputs.companyName.value,
    },
    function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err.name);
            console.log(err.message);
            console.log(err.stack);
        }
    }
);
```

Produces:

```
Error 
Company Name must be at least 5 characters in company insert
Error: Company Name must be at least 5 characters in company insert
    at getErrorObject (collection2.js:498)
    at doValidate (collection2.js:470)
    at Collection.Mongo.Collection.(:3000/anonymous function) [as insert] (http://localhost:3000/packages/aldeed_collection2.js?hash=9ed657993899f5a7b4df81355fd11d6b77396b85:286:14)
    at Blaze.TemplateInstance.helloOnCreated (main.js:10)
    at blaze.js?hash=51f4a3bdae106610ee48d8eff291f3628713d847:3398
    at Function.Template._withTemplateInstanceFunc (blaze.js?hash=51f4a3bdae106610ee48d8eff291f3628713d847:3769)
    at fireCallbacks (blaze.js?hash=51f4a3bdae106610ee48d8eff291f3628713d847:3394)
    at Blaze.View.<anonymous> (blaze.js?hash=51f4a3bdae106610ee48d8eff291f3628713d847:3474)
    at fireCallbacks (blaze.js?hash=51f4a3bdae106610ee48d8eff291f3628713d847:2014)
    at Object.Tracker.nonreactive (tracker.js:603)
```

The attribute `err.error` in contrast is part of [the `Meteor.Error`](https://docs.meteor.com/api/methods.html#Meteor-Error), which is thrown if the insert fails inside a [Meteor Method](https://docs.meteor.com/api/methods.html#Meteor-methods).

This would be the case for example in such code:

```
Meteor.call('someInserMethod', { company_name: 'abc' }, (err, res) => {
  console.log(err) // this error is a Meteor.Error
})
```